# Difficulty with DependencyProperties

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties, windows-phone

I'm having a bit of trouble with dependency properties on my Windows Phone Mango app. Here are two controls whose font size I'd like to change dynamically:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=ParagraphItems, Path=DataContext.TextScale}" />
<local:HyperlinkTextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=ParagraphItems, Path=DataContext.TextScale}"  />
```

The `TextBlock` works fine, but the `HyperlinkTextBlock` does not. `HyperlinkTextBlock` is a class I've made:

```
<UserControl
  <!-- ... -->
  >

    <RichTextBox x:Name="LayoutRoot" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}">
        <Paragraph x:Name="BaseParagraph" />
    </RichTextBox> 

</UserControl>

public partial class HyperlinkTextBlock : UserControl { /* ... */ }
```

I'm not sure what I need to do in `HyperlinkTextBlock` to make it so it can receive `FontSize` values when it is declared in XAML. I tried binding to the property in `HyperlinkTextBlock.xaml`, and notifying when the property changes in code-behind:

```
    public new double FontSize
    {
        get
        {
            return base.FontSize;
        }
        set
        {
            base.FontSize = value;
            onPropChanged("FontSize");
        }
    }
```

(It's `new` because `UserControl` already has a `FontSize` property - shouldn't I just be able to use that?)

I also tried creating an entirely new dependency property:

```
    public static readonly new DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FontSize",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(HyperlinkTextBlock),
        new PropertyMetadata(20, new PropertyChangedCallback(onFontSizeChanged)));

    public new double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void onFontSizeChanged(DependencyObject dependObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((HyperlinkTextBlock)dependObj).LayoutRoot.FontSize = (double)e.NewValue;
    }
```

Similarly, this did not work. At runtime, it gives the error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Default value type does not match type of property.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(Boolean fIsAttachedDP, String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata propertyMetadata, Boolean readOnly)
       at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata defaultMetadata)
       at MyApp.Views.HyperlinkTextBlock..cctor()
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
       at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.<>c__DisplayClass30.<GetCreateObjectDelegate>b__2a()
       at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.CreateInstance(UInt32 customTypeId)
       at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.CreateInstance(XamlTypeToken inXamlType, XamlQualifiedObject& newObject)
```

What is the right way to go about doing this?

**Update**:

If I just set `FontSize` directly on `HyperlinkTextBlock`:

```
     <local:HyperlinkTextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,15" FontSize="33.0" />
     <local:HyperlinkTextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,15" FontSize="40" />
```

And remove anything about `FontSize` from `HyperlinkTextBlock` itself:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="LayoutRoot" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Paragraph x:Name="BaseParagraph" />
</RichTextBox>
```

Then there is no observable effect of setting the font size. (The two text blocks declared above appear identical.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am not getting something, but why do you define FontSize as an attached property? I would go with a simple dependency property, and to avoid any confusion, I would give it a different name than FontSize (e. g. HyperlinkFontSize in this case), so I would do something like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HyperlinkFontSize = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "HyperlinkFontSize",
    typeof(double),
    typeof( HyperlinkTextBlock ),
    new PropertyMetadata( 20.0, onFontSizeChanged) ) );
```

(Note that you do not have to provide the name of the delegate type when you pass the event handler.)

And then do the binding like this:

```
<local:HyperlinkTextBlock Text="{Binding}" HyperlinkFontSize="{Binding ElementName=ParagraphItems, Path=DataContext.TextScale}" />
```

And one last thing: at first you tried to implement the FontSize as an ordinary property (with change notification). That never should work, because the target of data binding always has to be a dependency property (although the source can be any CLR property, even without change notification), as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

---

UPDATE: Another approach would be to bind the RichTextbox.FontSize property to the FontSize property of the user control, something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="hyperlinkTextboxUserControl" ...>

    <RichTextBox x:Name="LayoutRoot" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=hyperlinkTextboxUserControl}">
        <Paragraph x:Name="BaseParagraph" />
    </RichTextBox> 

</UserControl>
```

That way you do not need the extra dependency property, and you can simply set the FontSize on the local:HyperlinkTextBlock like you originally did.

Comment: This works. Thanks. (Is there some way I can use the inherited `FontSize` instead of defining my own version?)

Comment: Added an approach to the answer to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Change the dependency property code like this:

```
public static readonly new DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "FontSize",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(HyperlinkTextBlock),
    new PropertyMetadata((double)20, new PropertyChangedCallback(onFontSizeChanged)));
```

An int is not a double...

Comment: Possible alternative syntax: `20.0` will automatically type-infer to `double`, and `20D` explicitly specifies your intent that the literal `20` should be typed as such.

Comment: @TomW - yes, I chose this syntax because makes the answer clearest. In real life I use 20.0

Answer (score 0):

Unless something's different between Silverlight 5 and Windows Phone's Silverlight, the FontSize value should automatically be inherited from its parent. You don't need to created any dependency properties, and you don't need to make any bindings inside your UserControl. I just tested the following (on PC though) and it worked:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.HyperlinkTextBlock"
      <!-- ... -->
    >    
        <RichTextBox x:Name="LayoutRoot" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Paragraph x:Name="BaseParagraph">HyperlinkTextBox text</Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>  
</UserControl>
```

and

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <system:Double x:Key="SomethingToBindTo">28.0</system:Double>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <TextBlock  Text="TextBlock text" FontSize="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomethingToBindTo}}" />
    <my:HyperLinkTextBlock FontSize="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomethingToBindTo}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This was the result:

[image: result]

Update:

**Make sure to remove/comment the FontSize property you added, or my example won't work.**

If that still doesn't work for you, and since Silverlight 4 and earlier doesn't have the FindAncestor mark-up extension, perhaps name your UserControl and use that to bind your RichTextBox to.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.HyperlinkTextBox" Name="UserControlRoot"
      <!-- ... -->
    >   
        <RichTextBox x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     FontSize="{Binding ElementName=UserControlRoot, Path=FontSize}">
            <Paragraph x:Name="BaseParagraph">Text</Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Windows Phone does not run SL5, and this does not work for me - OP updated